# Removing repeated duplicated characters

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have a string in my stored proc like `',,,sam,,bob,'` or `',,,'`
from the above string I have to delete multiple commas from it, it must look like 
`'sam,bob,'` or only if  `',,,'`  then  `''` .
I must use only Sql Server Functions.
Im using Sql Server 2008 and .Net 3.5

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any chance you can do this before you insert/pass the data?  If so, it would probably be easier to do this using code.

Comment: its pretty OLD stored proc. Contains more than 4k lines of code. So cant while insert/pass. Im open to write a UDF in SQL Server not through Code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works for strings that are exclusively commas or have up to 398 contiguous commas.

```
 SELECT 
     CASE 
         WHEN TargetString NOT LIKE '%[^,]%' 
             THEN '' /*The string is exclusively commas*/
         ELSE 
            REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(TargetString,
            REPLICATE(',',16),','), /*399/16 = 24 remainder 15*/
            REPLICATE(',',8),','),  /* 39/ 8 =  4 remainder 7*/
            REPLICATE(',',4),','),  /* 11/ 4 =  2 remainder 3*/
            REPLICATE(',',2),','),  /*  5/ 2 =  2 remainder 1*/
            REPLICATE(',',2),',')   /*  3/ 2 =  1 remainder 1*/
         END
 FROM T
```

Add extra powers of 2 at the top if you need more or remove from the top if you need less. The comments by each stage indicate the smallest number that this stage will not deal with successfully.

All the comment lines are in this format

```
/*  L/D    =  Q remainder R */

D:    Corresponds to the length of the string generated by `REPLICATE`
R:    Is always D-1
Q+R:  Form L for the next step
```

So to extend the series upwards with another `REPLICATE(',',32),',')` stage

```
D = 32 
R = 31
Q = 368 (399-31)
L = (368 * 32) + 31 = 11807
```

So that would deal with sections of commas up to 11,806 characters.

Answer (score 6):

I would suggest a UDF to do this.  Since the UDF I am about to suggest doesn't touch any tables, the performance should be pretty good.

```
CREATE Function [dbo].[CleanDuplicates](@Data VarChar(8000), @DuplicateChar VarChar(1))
Returns VarChar(8000)
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
Begin

    Set @Data = @DuplicateChar + @Data

    While PATINDEX('%' + @DuplicateChar + @DuplicateChar + '%',@Data) > 0
        Set @Data = REPLACE(@Data, @DuplicateChar + @DuplicateChar,@DuplicateChar)

    Return Right(@Data, Len(@Data)-1)

End
```

You can test the function like this:

```
Select dbo.CleanDuplicates(',,,', ',')
Select dbo.CleanDuplicates(',,,sam,,bob,', ',')
```

Comment: when using scalar UDF, performance will be not "pretty good" because it will be recalculated for every row

Comment: @Dalex, thanks for your comment.  Unfortunately you are over-simplifying the scalar UDF performance problem.  I suppose you would be surprised to learn that your query is many times slower than mine.  Scalar UDF's often exhibit bad performance when the UDF uses a table.  Since this UDF doesn't, the performance is good.  I also like that it's simple and easy to understand, fast to code, and easy to debug.

Comment: It's best practice to use the `WITH SCHEMABINDING` option for UDFs that do not do data access. Not sure if this benefits straightforward `SELECT`s in any way but definitely of benefit if the UDF is used in an `UPDATE` statement [as described here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2006/05/12/596424.aspx)

Comment: @Martin, thanks for the heads up.  I didn't know. In this case, it made a huge difference in performance.  Thank you very much for letting me know about this. In this case, it made a straight up select become approximately 40x faster.

Comment: Wow, definitely worth doing then!

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
SELECT @Parameter AS 'BEFORE'
BEGIN
WHILE CHARINDEX(',,', @Parameter) > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT @Parameter = REPLACE(@Parameter, ',,',',') 
    END
SELECT @Parameter AS 'AFTER'
END
```

Answer (score 2):

> **George Mastros wrote:**
>
> ---
>
> I would suggest a UDF to do this. Since the UDF I am about to suggest
>   doesn't touch any tables, the performance should be pretty good.

I agree that "memory only" Scalar UDF's are quite fast.  In fact, I actually used one of George's Scalar UDFs, which solved the "Initial Caps" problem, to demonstrate that sometimes "Set Based" code **ISN'T** always the best way to go.

However, Martin Smith (another poster on this very thread) was definitely on the right track.  In this case, "Set Based" is still the way to go.  Of course, anyone can make an unsubstantiated claim as to performance so let's heat this up with a performance demonstration.

To demonstrate, we first need some test data.  A LOT of test data because both of the functions we're going to test run nasty fast.  Here's the code to build a million row test table.

```
--===== Conditionally drop the test table 
     -- to make reruns in SSMS easier
     IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#MyHead','U') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #MyHead
GO
--===== Create and populate the test table on-the-fly.
     -- This builds a bunch of GUIDs and removes the dashes from them to 
     -- increase the chances of duplicating adjacent characters.
     -- Not to worry.  This takes less than 7 seconds to run because of
     -- the "Pseudo Cursor" created by the CROSS JOIN.
 SELECT TOP 1000000
        RowNum     = IDENTITY(INT,1,1),
        SomeString = REPLACE(CAST(NEWID() AS VARCHAR(36)),'-','')
   INTO #MyHead
   FROM sys.all_columns ac1
  CROSS JOIN sys.all_columns ac2
;
GO
```

No need to repost George's fine function here but I do need to post mine.  The following function produces the same result as George's does.  It looks like an "iTVF" (Inline Table Valued Function) and it is but it only returns one value.  That's why Microsoft calls them "Inline Scalar Functions" (I call them "iSFs" for short).

```
 CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CleanDuplicatesJBM
        (@Data VARCHAR(8000), @DuplicateChar VARCHAR(1))
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN 
 SELECT Item =  STUFF(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
                    @DuplicateChar+@Data COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_BIN,
                REPLICATE(@DuplicateChar,33),@DuplicateChar),
                REPLICATE(@DuplicateChar,17),@DuplicateChar),
                REPLICATE(@DuplicateChar, 9),@DuplicateChar),
                REPLICATE(@DuplicateChar, 5),@DuplicateChar),
                REPLICATE(@DuplicateChar, 3),@DuplicateChar),
                REPLICATE(@DuplicateChar, 2),@DuplicateChar),
                REPLICATE(@DuplicateChar, 2),@DuplicateChar)
                ,1,1,'')
;
GO
```

First, let's test George's Scalar UDF.  Please read the comments about why we're not using SET STATISTICS TIME ON here.

```
/******************************************************************************
 Test George's code.
 Since Scalar Functions don't work well with SET STATISTICS TIME ON, we measure
 duration a different way.  We'll also throw away the result in a "Bit Bucket"
 variable because we're trying to measure the performance of the function 
 rather than how long it takes to display or store results.
******************************************************************************/
--===== Declare some obviously named variables
DECLARE @StartTime DATETIME,
        @BitBucket VARCHAR(36)
;
--===== Start the "Timer"
 SELECT @StartTime = GETDATE()
;
--===== Run the test on the function
 SELECT @BitBucket = [dbo].[CleanDuplicates](SomeString,'A')
   FROM #MyHead
;
--===== Display the duration in milliseconds
  PRINT DATEDIFF(ms,@StartTime,GETDATE())
;
--===== Run the test a total of 5 times
GO 5
```

Here are the returns from that "fiver" run...

```
Beginning execution loop
15750
15516
15543
15480
15510
Batch execution completed 5 times.
(Average is 15,559 on my 10 year old, single 1.8Ghz CPU)
```

Now, we'll run the "iSF" version...

```
/******************************************************************************
 Test Jeff's code.
 Even though this uses an "iSF" (Inline Scalar Function), we'll test exactly
 the same way that we tested George's code so we're comparing apples-to-apples.
 This includes throwing away the result in a "Bit Bucket" variable because 
 we're trying to measure the performance of the function rather than how long 
 it takes to display or store results.
******************************************************************************/
--===== Declare some obviously named variables
DECLARE @StartTime DATETIME,
        @BitBucket VARCHAR(36)
;
--===== Start the "Timer"
 SELECT @StartTime = GETDATE()
;
--===== Run the test on the function
 SELECT @BitBucket = cleaned.ITEM
   FROM #MyHead
  CROSS APPLY [dbo].[CleanDuplicatesJBM](SomeString,'A') cleaned
;
--===== Display the duration in milliseconds
  PRINT DATEDIFF(ms,@StartTime,GETDATE())
;
--===== Run the test a total of 5 times
GO 5
```

Here are the results from that run.

```
Beginning execution loop
6856
6810
7020
7350
6996
Batch execution completed 5 times.
(Average is 7,006 {more than twice as fast} on my 10 year old, single 1.8Ghz CPU)
```

My point ISN'T that George's code is bad.  Not at all.  In fact, I use Scalar UDFs when there is no "single query" solution.  I'll also state and back George up by saying that not all "single query" solutions are always the best.

Just don't stop looking for them when it comes to UDFs. ;-)

Comment: Heh... yep.  I realize I responded to a thread that's more than a year old.  I hope someone can use the tip even after all this time.

Answer (score 0):

Your solutions are good but

1. it is comma only
2. i hate loop-based TSQL code ;-)

so i wrote based on Marcin solution set-based universal code for replacement of every declared kind of duplicates:

```
DECLARE @Duplicate NVARCHAR(100)= '#$'
DECLARE @TestString NVARCHAR(MAX)= 'test_test__f##f2$$g'
DECLARE @Replacement NVARCHAR(MAX)= ''
DECLARE @OutputString NVARCHAR(MAX)= @teststring ;
WITH    numbers
          AS ( SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY o.object_id, o2.object_id ) Number
               FROM     sys.objects o
                        CROSS JOIN sys.objects o2
             ),
        chars
          AS ( SELECT   SUBSTRING(@Duplicate, 1, 1) CHAR ,
                        CAST(1 AS INT) [LEVEL]
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   SUBSTRING(@Duplicate, numbers.Number, 1) CHAR ,
                        CAST(numbers.Number AS INT) [LEVEL]
               FROM     numbers
                        JOIN chars ON chars.Level + 1 = numbers.Number
               WHERE    LEN(SUBSTRING(@Duplicate, numbers.Number, 1)) > 0
             ),
        Replicated
          AS ( SELECT   REPLICATE(CHAR, numbers.number) Repl ,
                        numbers.Number
               FROM     chars
                        CROSS JOIN numbers
             )
    SELECT  @OutputString = REPLACE(@OutputString, Repl, @Replacement)
    FROM    replicated
    WHERE   number <= LEN(@TestString)

SELECT  @OutputString
```

You can declare every kind of char in Duplicate string and  every  replacement string in @Replacement.
Additional gain IMHO is that i search for replacement only in range of maximum length of input string

Comment: >>2.i hate loop-based TSQL code ;-)  If that's true, you might want to get out of the habit of using rCTEs (Recursive CTEs) for counters.  rCTEs are good for some things but absolutely horrible for counting compared to other methods because, behind the scenes, they're a horrible loop on a Temp Table.  Here's a link to an article on the subject. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/74118/

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
SELECT REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(',,,sam,,bob,', ',', ' ')),' ', ',')
```