# Conditionally replace multiple instances of a character with "n" instances of that

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, t-sql

Related question:

[Replace multiple instance of a character with a single instance in sql](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34792494/2993606)

**Requirement:**

I have the below strings:

```
Heelloo
Heeelloo
Heeeelloo
Heeeeeelloo
Heeeeeeeelloo
.
.
.
Heeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeelloo
```

**Expected output:**

If the instances of the letter 'e' is in multiples of 8, the expectation is 'ee'. For all other instances, it should be 'e'. So,

**1.** `Heeeeeeeello` should be `Heello` <<-- 8 instances of 'e' replaced by 'ee'

**2.**  `Heeeeeeeeeello` should be `Heeello` <<-- 8 instances of 'e' replaced by 'ee' and then rest 2 'e''s replaced by a single 'e'.

**3.** `Heeello` should give `Hello`

***Version I am using*** :

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 10.0.7365.0 (X64) Jul 28 2015 00:39:54 Copyright (c) 
Microsoft Corporation Parallel Data Warehouse (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> 
(Build 9200: )
```

Comment: Easier to do outside SQL, but I guess you could do a while-loop looping over your string, and then continue to replace characters for that string until no more replacements are done, and then move to next field. Not terrible effective, so I'd consider a solution outside SQL.

Comment: Is this question based on a real-life business case?

Comment: Did you read [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34793689/5070879) for your previous question which handle your case or  is it incorrect for you? It is rude not to leave a comment.

Comment: It's really stupid to downvote a perfectly valid question without any justification. The reason this is a new question is because by the time I was about to edit my first question, Gordon had answered that.

Comment: @lad2025 - I have been away from my system, so couldn't leave a comment, but I upvoted it. Appreciate your efforts.

Comment: @TT. - this is what happens when one asks a very similar question the second time. I got two unnecessary downvotes. Anyway, Yes, it is based on a real life situation. One column has a lot of unnecessary spaces in it. Got to know that if there are 8 spaces, it indicates a new paragraph. anything lesser should be converted to a single space.

Comment: I gave you a + to offset the loss. In any case it is a good idea to start your question with mentioning the business case, that helps give the question some gravitas. GL!

Comment: If I come across such questions on SO, I just answer it, howsoever non-practical they may sound. Also, IMO not every question needs to be practical. For example - I might suddenly be wondering about how to do something and then ask it here to know how others would approach it. The kind of answers @lad2025 and gordon_linoff gave, those were extraordinary. That's why I love this site. So many people have so many valuable ideas in their mind , which is difficult to get from any book. But..then it's just my opinion. To say a question better be practical is a little discouraging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on 
[T-SQL String Manipulation Tips and Techniques, Part 1](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/t-sql-string-manipulation-tips-and-techniques-part-1) especially part `Replacing Multiple Contiguous Spaces With a Single Space and idea of Peter Larsson, a SQL Server MVP`:

> Then, the solution involves three steps (assuming the token is ~):
>
> 1. Replace in @str each occurrence of ' ' (space) with '~ ' (token plus space).
> 2. Replace in the result of the previous step each occurrence of ' ~' (space plus token) with '' (an empty string).
> 3. Replace in the result of the previous step each occurrence of '~ ' (token plus space) with ' ' (space).

```
CREATE TABLE #tab(val NVARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO #tab
SELECT 'Hello'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Heello'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Heeello'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Heeeello'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Heeeeeello'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Heeeeeeeello'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Heeeeeeeeeello';

-- version for one vowel(it can be enhanced to handle other if needed)
SELECT val,
cleaned = REPLACE(
           REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
            REPLACE(REPLACE(val, REPLICATE('e', 8), '^^')
              , 'e', '~ ')
            , ' ~', '')
          , '~ ', 'e')
          ,'^^','ee')              
FROM #tab;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/423720)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔════════════════╦═════════╗
║      val       ║ cleaned ║
╠════════════════╬═════════╣
║ Hello          ║ Hello   ║
║ Heello         ║ Hello   ║
║ Heeello        ║ Hello   ║
║ Heeeello       ║ Hello   ║
║ Heeeeeello     ║ Hello   ║
║ Heeeeeeeello   ║ Heello  ║
║ Heeeeeeeeeello ║ Heeello ║
╚════════════════╩═════════╝
```

---

From comment (alomost identical situation like in link above ):

> One column has a lot of unnecessary spaces in it. Got to know that if
>   there are 8 spaces, it indicates a new paragraph. anything lesser
>   should be converted to a single space.

You could easily adapt it to your new needs using `SPACE(8)` instead of replicating `e` 8 times and `REPLACE` to new line `CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)`

```
DECLARE @text NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'Line    1.        Line     two.';

SELECT @text=REPLACE(
               REPLACE(
                  REPLACE(
                     REPLACE(@text, SPACE(8), CHAR(13) + CHAR(10))
                  , ' ', '~ ')
               , ' ~', '')
             , '~ ', ' ');

PRINT @text;
```

Output:

```
Line 1.
Line two.
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo2`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/424061)**</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

Try this user defined function:

```
CREATE  FUNCTION TrimDuplicates(@String varchar(max))
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @String=REPLACE(@String,'eeeeeeee','!@#$%')
    while CHARINDEX('ee',@String)>0 BEGIN SET @String=REPLACE(@String,'ee','e') END
    while CHARINDEX('oo',@String)>0 BEGIN SET @String=REPLACE(@String,'oo','o') END
    SET @String=REPLACE(@String,'!@#$%','ee')
    RETURN @String
END
```

Example Usage:

```
select dbo.TrimDuplicates ('Heeeeeeeeeello')
```

returns Heeello

**Update**
If you want to use it without UDF:

```
DECLARE @String varchar(max)='Heeeeeeeelloo'
SET @String=REPLACE(@String,'eeeeeeee','!@#$%')
while CHARINDEX('ee',@String)>0 BEGIN SET @String=REPLACE(@String,'ee','e') END
while CHARINDEX('oo',@String)>0 BEGIN SET @String=REPLACE(@String,'oo','o') END
SET @String=REPLACE(@String,'!@#$%','ee')
SELECT @String
```

Comment: Thanks, upvoted. it does get me what I want. But I would prefer something that doesn't require me to create a UDF.

Comment: @AtheerMostafa I would like it to see hot to use it with multiple rows, not with single value variable

Comment: @lad multiple rows / queries is accomplished using the udf (it was not initial requirement although it is a preference from his later comment) as follows:
select dbo.TrimDuplicates(val) FROM #tab